# DataTables + yadcf Add a Class to Filtered Column

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, yadcf, jquery-datatables-rails

Is there a way to add a class to filtered columns using [yadcf](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf)?

As for now, When I filter a column on my table using a select box provided by yadcf, I can't seem to show that the column is filtered.

I want to add a class to the columns `<th>` so that I can style it to show my users that the corresponding column is filtered.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it using the `.inuse` class from yadcf.
It's a class that yadcf applies on a filtered column.
All I had to do was add 
`$(".yadcf-filter.inuse").closest("th").addClass("bg-filter");` to my DataTables' `drawCallback`.

Answer (score 1):

yadcf allows you to add custom `class` on the filter itself by using the [style_class](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/blob/a3600ca8d815b70c43247564e07f099fe762a42c/src/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js#L251-L255) property and anyway *IMO* making entire column look differently when filtered is too much